# web3.eth.getBlock isn't triggered

Tags: web3js, transactions, nodejs, blocks, hash

Basically, i want get the callback result of first method to get each index value in pass it to the second method to scan this value, in this case is an ethereum transaction to get the input value. The problem is the callback named "cb" isn't triggered.

code:

```
var tx;

web3.eth.getBlock(6339515, function(err, result){
    for(var i = 0; i <= result.transactions.length; i++){
        tx = result.transactions[i];
        getInputTransaction(tx)
        .then(function() {} )
        .catch(function(error) {
            console.log('error: \n' + err);
        });
    }
})

async function getInputTransaction(tx) {
    web3.eth.getTransaction(tx, function(err, cb){
        console.log('got here');
        let decodeInput = web3.utils.hexToAscii(cb.input);
        decodeInput = decodeInput.split("_").pop();
        if(!err){
            console.log(cb);
            console.log('\nInput decoded: ' + '\u001b[1;32m' + decodeInput + '\u001b[0m');
        }else{
            console.log('error: ' + error);
    }}
    )
}
```

What am i missing here?

Comment: What version of web3.js are you on?

Comment: web3js 1.0.0-beta.37

Comment: First of all, please upgrade to v1.2.6.

Comment: Also, get rid of the global `var tx`. It is redundant in your script.

Comment: Also, in your implementation, function `getInputTransaction` doesn't need to be declared `async`.

Comment: The callback is triggered just fine on v1.2.1. You may see a runtime exception on `cb` being undefined in the other callback (the one which is passed to `web3.eth.getTransaction`), but that's a different issue (you probably need to check `err` before using `cb`).

Comment: Wow, wait. You're not supposed to fix your question according to the answers that you receive! If any of these answers answer your question, then please accept that answer and post your new problem as a different question.

Comment: sorry for that, error continues, i put the edited code following your instructions just to show, already removed it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The callback passed to `getBlock` is triggered just fine under web3.js v1.2.1.

A few side issues that you might want to fix:

1. The global `var tx` seems redundant
2. Function `getInputTransaction` doesn't need to be declared `async`
3. In the callback passed to `getBlock`, ensure `err == null` before using `result`
4. In the callback passed to `getTransaction`, ensure `err == null` before using `cb`

Comment: Thanks for helping.                                                                                                                                    
Did all the instructions and yes, err is returning null, which is right, isn't?                                 
If a change if(err != null) to if(err == null) of getBlock i got an error "'input' of undefined"  Debuggin shows "cb" continues not be triggered.

Comment: @RAFAELDASILVA: Yes, it should be "ensure `err == null`" in my answer. I don't understand your question though, because there is no `cb` parameter in the callback that you pass to `getBlock`. You should ensure `err == null` in both of the callbacks.

Comment: i meant when i debbug, "cb" of getInputTransaction is not triggered because i got the follow error: "'input' of undefined". according to the documentation, "input" parameter is one of variables of the callback parameter "cb"

Comment: @RAFAELDASILVA: Yes, but when `err != null`, the `input` parameter is probably not provided.

Comment: even with `err == null` i got "input' of undefined"

Comment: if I pass a simple string e.g **0x5c122805284ec847ad725840f5af0be2729d85a6be46fb2c16c0a885b03ad46d** as parameter to `getInputTransaction(tx)` in `web3.eth.getBlock` it works well.

Comment: @RAFAELDASILVA: So check `if (error == null && cb != undefined)`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/107212/discussion-between-rafael-da-silva-and-goodvibration).